# Jenkins unable to locate files on my computer

Tags: android, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

when ever I try to build my android project on jenkins it fails by saying :

Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /home/tanzeelrana/git/eventmatrix-cordova-app/mysteryshopper_version2
[mysteryshopper_version2] $ ant -Dlabel=trial1-9 clean debug
Buildfile: /home/tanzeelrana/git/eventmatrix-cordova-app/mysteryshopper_version2/build.xml

**BUILD FAILED**

/home/tanzeelrana/git/eventmatrix-cordova-app/mysteryshopper_version2/build.xml:90: Cannot find /home/tanzeelrana/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml imported from /home/tanzeelrana/git/eventmatrix-cordova-app/mysteryshopper_version2/build.xml

Total time: 0 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

on line 90 in my build.xml file I have a tag with the following in it :

import file="/home/tanzeelrana/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml"

does anyone know why it is unable to locate this file ? the file exist at the exact path ....

Comment: Maybe security restrictions. Jenkins normally runs as the user jenkins, which may not have acces to your home directory. As you are using Git, I would recommend Gerrit and using the Gerrit Trigger plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins usually runs with its own user (jenkins),
so it is probably an issue of permissions.

Try printing the current user from within your Jenkins job.

**EDIT:**
See here about running Jenkins as a daemon -
it also shows how to set it to run as a different user than 'jenkins':

[**Installing Jenkins as a Unix daemon**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Unix+daemon)

Comment: is there a way to allow jenkins the permissions ?

Comment: so I changed the permissions for the folders that jenkins was accessing. but now I have another problem ... when the build process try's to create a zip for the apk of my android application it is giving me a permission denied error again.

Comment: -package:
[apkbuilder] Current build type is different than previous build: forced apkbuilder run.
[apkbuilder] Creating template-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
 [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...

Comment: BUILD FAILED
/home/tanzeelrana/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:1026: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/tanzeelrana/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:1028: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/tanzeelrana/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:340: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/tanzeelrana/android-sdk-linux/tools/zipalign": error=13, Permission denied
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615)

Comment: This is a pure unix-permissions issue - you are missing permissions on that folder. Can try putting both users on the same group (assuming the group has enough privilages to write to that folder).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156569/jenkins-unable-to-run-build-tools-17-0-0-aapt

Comment: So I got that running but now I have this problem. it wont detect files on the server. I know the files are there. the permission on the file is -rwxr-xr-x

root@ott-ci-01:/usr/local/lib/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/17.0.0# ls -la /usr/local/lib/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/17.0.0/aapt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1122758 Jun 17 10:07

If any one of you can help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156569/jenkins-unable-to-run-build-tools-17-0-0-aapt

Comment: Try listing files in that area from within your job - I suspect you are missing permissions on some higher level in the folder-tree (again - Unix-permissions issue of some sort).