# jenkins unable to run " /build-tools/17.0.0/aapt "

Tags: ant, jenkins, automation, continuous-integration, hudson

does anyone know why is jenkins unable to run this file and gives a no such file or directory error ?

the file is there. it has the following permissions :

root@ott-ci-01:/usr/local/lib/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/17.0.0# ls -la /usr/local/lib/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/17.0.0/aapt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1122758 Jun 17 10:07 /usr/local/lib/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/17.0.0/aapt

[image]

any ideas ?